# Does Foundry Data Connection support NFS transfer?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

Is it possible for a Data Connection agent to connect to NFS in order to transfer data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for connecting directly, however, you could mount the NFS on the agent host (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-an-nfs-share-in-linux/), and then just use a standard Directory source to ingest the data.